# single persistent scp connection program options

Tags: windows-7, command-line, putty, scp, sftp

I'm using PSCP (part of the putty package) to make several connections to a server but my boss would like to reduce the number of connections to 1.  Is there a Windows program like PSCP which only makes one connection and keeps that connection open for the duration of the session and also has a command line interface?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can download winscp from http://winscp.net/eng/index.php that will keep the connection open.

yes, you can use that through commandline as well.

http://winscp.net/eng/docs/commandline, but i am not sure if you can hold the connection open with cli.